# How to choose which GLIBC_version in python when I use blender to render with python

Tags: python, blender, glibc

I ran `blender -b --python path/to/my/pythonfile.py`.
But an error was thrown out that `version` GLIBC_2.28' not found`.
My latest GLIBC version is 'GLIBC_2.27'.
I have no authority to upgrade GLIBC version in the linux server.
How can I choose the GLIBC version?

I have searched Internet for a lot of solutions.
But I haven't found a way to solve it.
I am wondering if there is a possibility to choose GLIBC version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My latest GLIBC version is 'GLIBC_2.27'. I have no authority to upgrade GLIBC version in the linux server. How can I choose the GLIBC version?

You can't (at least not easily; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) if you really want to do that).

What you should do instead is get an *appropriate* `blender` binary compiled for your system (you probably copied this binary from another system with newer GLIBC; *don't* do that).